# Yii2 - activeform ajax validation with normal form submit

Tags: yii, yii2

Using the `beforeSubmit` function of `yii.activeForm.js`, how can I make it perform a normal form submit when validation passes?

I have tried the following:

```
$('.ajax-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (event) {
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    var type = form.attr('method');
    var data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.errors.length != 0) {
                form.yiiActiveForm('updateMessages', result.errors, true);
            }
            else if (result.confirmed == true) {
                $('.confirm-panel').show();
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
       },
       error: function() {
           alert('Error');
       }
    });

    // prevent default form submission
    return false;
});
```

Controller:

```
public function actionProcess()
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $return_array = [
            'errors' => [],
            'confirmed' => false,
        ];

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $return_array['errors'] = ActiveForm::validate($model);

        if ($model->confirm == 1) {
            $return_array['confirmed'] = true;
        }

        return $this->asJson($return_array);
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['success']);
    }

    return $this->render('process', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

As you can see I am also trying to return additional data in my AJAX response. The problem I am having is the `return true` in the ajax success isn't working. I can't seem to break out of the function. I have also tried `form.submit()` here but this just does a submit loop via AJAX.

By the way I am not using `enableAjaxValidation` because I have some additional custom validation that happens in my controller. So this is why I have created my own custom handler for this.

Comment: you cannot `return true` from the ajax `readystate` and why are you trying to send an ajax call to validate the form when yii provide you the option `enableAjaxValidation` and what are your custom validation methods that cannot be adjusted into the model and triggered via ajax ? you should add the code for your form `view` and controller `action`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam when the form is submitted (via ajax) it needs to return some custom html if validation passes, I have not been able to work out how to do this with `enableAjaxValidation`.

Comment: well if you can share we can sort it out if you like.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - added controller action code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't `return true` from within an ajax `success function` to continue form submission as it is `javascript` and the last line `return true` is already executed before the `response` is received so the form ain't going to submit by returning `true` inside the success function.

You need to use the event `afterValidate` if you want to submit your page manually after successful ajax validation rather than using `beforeSubmit` as it will go into an infinite loop if you try to submit the form using `$("form").submit()` inside the ajax success function. so change your line

```
$('.ajax-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (event) {
```

to

```
$('.ajax-form').on('afterValidate', function (event) {
```

and then change your success function to

```
success: function (result) {
            if (result.errors.length != 0) {
                form.yiiActiveForm('updateMessages', result.errors, true);
            }
            else if (result.confirmed == true) {
                $('.confirm-panel').show();
            }
            else {
                form.submit();
            }
       },
```

Hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Input validation should be made in models no matter if it's built in or custom. Then you can easily use the default ajax validation.

For creating custom validators check http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators

Answer (score 0):

you need not to write any such code for this propose. Yii can handle ajax validations it-self. only thing that you need to do is enable it in active form like.

```
php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
         'id' => 'contact-form',
         'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
 ]); ?>
```

and placing this code in controller after initialize $model.

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return = ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```